# Calling a javascript function, which is passed as a parameter from a javascript library

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm currently trying to implement the [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) javascript library into an angular 2 dart webapp.
I'm having problems porting this javascript code to dart though:

```
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar(
{
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var generated_events=[
        {
            title  : 'test',
            start  : '2016-08-08'
        }];
        callback(generated_events);
    },
    allDaySlot: false
    //More options can go here
});
```

I've gotten as far as being able to pass a dart function to the events parameter with this code:

```
context.callMethod(r'$',['#fullCalendar'])
        .callMethod('fullCalendar',[new JsObject.jsify({
        'events': (start, end, timezone, callback){
            print("called!");
            List<FullCalendarEvent> generated_events= [
                new FullCalendarEvent(title: "test", start: "2016-08-08")
            ];
            try{
                callback(generated_events);
            }catch(exception,stackTrace){
                print("Caught exception!");
                print(exception);
                print(stackTrace);
            }
        },
        'allDaySlot': false
        //more options can go here
    })]);
```

Where the FullCalendarEvent is a simple anoymous class structure:

```
@JS()
@anonymous
class FullCalendarEvent{
    external String get title;
    external set title(String v);

    external String get start;
    external set start(String v);

    external factory FullCalendarEvent({
        String title,
        String start
    });
}
```

However the `callback(generated_events);` throws this exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call$1' (callback.call$1 is not a function)
```

**Edit:**

With the help of Günter's replies I managed to fix the problem. Instead of doing `callback(generated_events);` I instead use `callback.apply([generated_events]);` Additionally instead of using

```
List<FullCalendarEvent> generated_events= [
    new FullCalendarEvent(title: "test", start: "2016-08-08")
];
```

I instead use:

```
var generated_events = new JsObject.jsify([{'title':'test','start':'2016-08-08'}]);
```

My working code looks like this:

```
context.callMethod(r'$',['#fullCalendar'])
    .callMethod('fullCalendar',[new JsObject.jsify({
        'events': (start, end, timezone, callback){
            print("called!");
            var generated_events = new JsObject.jsify([{'title':'test','start':'2016-08-08'}]);
            try{
                callback.apply([generated_events]);
            }catch(exception,stackTrace){
                print("Caught exception!");
                print(exception);
                print(stackTrace);
            }
        },
        'allDaySlot': false
        //more options can go here
    })]);
```

Comment: Seems you are mixing `dart:js` and `package:js` which isn't supported.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I just tried to pass an empty object(completely removed all the package:js parts of my code) to the callback function, and I still get the same NoSuchMethodError. I think the problem is related to dart simply not interpreting the callback parameter as a javascript function(since it's trying to call "callback.call$1").

Comment: Did you try to figure out what exactly you get passed as `callback`?

Comment: I've tried to do a print(callback), and this is the output: 

    `function (events) {
     callback(events);
  t.popLoading();
  }`. I however suspect that it might just be a string or such. I can't find any easy way to test what type the callback parameter has though. I'll look into trying to test the type of the callback variable.

Comment: Not sure but worth a try `callback.apply([generated_events])`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot Günter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JS function should be callable with

```
callback.apply([gen‌​erated_events])
```